# How to integrate location information into Twitter app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I'm trying to get a Twitter iPhone app working using Matt Gemmell's MGTwitterEngine. I can post tweets OK, but I can't work out how to attach location data to those tweets... anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used MGTwitterEngine but from looking at the code, it should be as simple as calling `sendUpdate:withLatitude:longitude:`. What have you tried? What did and what did not work? Please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks. I was using an old version of the engine, since I was using Ben Gottlieb's authentication thing... http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone
I will try the method you mention.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do post tweets with location information with MGTwitterEngine as of now. I am currently working on bringing the library up to date. You can check github.com/freeatnet/MGTwitterEngine/tree/v2-dev for updates. I'll be pushing a commit containing a method for geo-aware updates today.

UPD. See commit @ http://github.com/freeatnet/MGTwitterEngine/commit/512be99cca9f5787192633455300dcd788c7830c for location-aware updates.

Method signatures:

- (NSString *)sendUpdate:(NSString *)status;
- (NSString *)sendUpdate:(NSString *)status fromLocationLat:(float)locLat locationLong:(float)locLong;
- (NSString *)sendUpdate:(NSString *)status inReplyTo:(unsigned long long)updateID fromLocationLat:(float)locLat locationLong:(float)locLong;

Comment: The current version of MGTwitterEngine does have the sendUpdate:withLatitude:longitude: method